# Is it possible to use NBuilder to Build a collection of random strings?

Tags: .net, string, random, nbuilder

pretty simple question: can I use [NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/Documentation/Lists) to create a collection of *x number* of random strings?

I was trying...

```
// NOTE: Tags need to be lowercase.
return Builder<string>
    .CreateListOfSize(10)
    .WhereAll()
        .Has(x => x = randomGenerator.Phrase(15))
    .WhereTheFirst(1)
        .Has(x => x = "time")
    .AndTheNext(1)
        .Has(x => x = "place")
    .AndTheNext(1)
        .Has(x => x = "colour")
    .Build();
```

but it was run-time erroring, something about I needed to call some specific constructor or something.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NBuilder creates objects by using the default (parameterless) constructor.  The exception you are receiving is because the String class doesn't have a default constructor.

To create a list of random strings, you could use the Phrase method inside a loop.  Maybe not as clean as a single NBuilder chain, but it gets the job done:

```
   List<string> stringsList = new List<string>();
   var generator = new RandomGenerator();
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       stringsList.Add(generator.Phrase(15));
   }

   return stringsList;
```

Comment: so then NBuilder can't create random strings?

Comment: A random string - yes. A list of random strings using a single NBuilder chain of methods - not that I am aware of.  I've updated my answer to include a way of generating the list.

Answer (score 15):

Sorry about bringing an old thread back to life, but I just wanted to share this solution/hack:

```
var myList = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(el => generator.Phrase(10));
```

Your feedback is appreciated :)

Comment: `return Enumerable.Range(0, size).Select(el => GetRandom.String(10));` works too